# want to send post method parameter to server using son

Tags: android

I don't know to send Post method parameters to a server.. I'm new to android...

I need help in it..

below is my code in android

```
try
            {
                //param="SrvName=&MethodName=&Parameters=08 Mar 2017|07 Apr 2017|1|1|1|10112829|0|";

                url=new URL(u);

                con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setDoInput(true);

                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                JSONObject param   = new JSONObject();

                param.put();

                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                //os.write(param.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    InputStreamReader input=new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());

                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                    int res=input.read();
                    while (res!=-1)
                    {
                        char ch=(char) res;
                        response.append(res);
                        res=input.read();
                    }
                    input.close();

                    System.out.println(response);
                }

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My post parameters:

```
{
    "SrvName":"",
    "MethodName":"",
    "Parameters":"08 Mar 2017|07 Apr 2017|1|1|1|10112829|0|"
}
```

i want to send this parameter to server.

do i have to use any son object because i want to send this parameter using json.

Comment: using the HttpUrlConnection is really painful , id suggest for you to a higher level library , like [Android faster networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) its built on the top of okhttp [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) . good luck

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP` methods should be executed using `AsyncTask` which has several methods needed to be override. `onPreExecute`, `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`. sending the post values should be like the following:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // your variables ...
        JSONObject user_info = new JSONObject();
        try {
            user_info.put("USER_NAME", name);
            user_info.put("USER_PWD", pass);


            Log.d("user_info", user_info.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("sending userinfo", "error in creating json object");
            return dta;
        }

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();//init client

        HttpResponse response = null;

        // Send Data Using Post Method
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(your_url);
            StringEntity en = new StringEntity(user_info.toString()); //build data to be sent
            en.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json"));
            post.setEntity(en);

            response = client.execute(post);
            if (response == null) {
                Log.e("error in response", "server not respond");
            } else {
                Log.d("msg", "send data ");
                // now you got the response...parse it 
                InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
               // and others coders...

     }
```